# Can the wiki concept be expanded?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community-wiki, wikipedia

Pardon me if this rambles just a little. I have been an active member of StackOverflow for around a year now, but I have only started reading and listening more to Jeff and Joel's thoughts on where they see the concept going, and an idea was kind of simmering there.

The thing that has really built the StackOverflow community is the ready availability of truly useful information, and the ability to add information to that growing stack. One thing that I have been looking to see for a while is some place that just contains the hard information about the specific subjects. Think the wikipedia idea but focused more to an individual communities needs.

My thought was something like wikipedia in terms of you could have an article on LINQ and then users with sufficient rep could attach questions relevant to that article. I don't know if this concept make sufficient sense or not, but thought that I would throw it out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would require a rather significant shift in thought on how we use the site, allowing questions to be generated that are simply attempts to organize lists of questions.

I'm not sure it's worthwhile, though - it would really only help those people that are:

- Browsing generally
- Learning a new language

Whereas stackoverflow was meant largely to serve as a site to get answers to questions - in other words, you have a problem, SO should have the solution, and if it doesn't you can post it and reasonably expact an answer quickly.

However, the content is licensed, and the read only API is available, so I expect that many sites are going to spring up to provide this (and many other) service.

So if you want to see a nice tutorial on LINQ, some site that caters to LINQ developers would set such a guide to LINQ SO questions.

But I don't see it as a good fit for being hosted by SO itself.

Answer (score 2):

> My thought was something like wikipedia in terms of you could have an article on LINQ and then users with sufficient rep could attach questions relevant to that article.

I don't think this makes sense. Remember we have *aspects* of wiki in the design, but everything should be Q&A focused.

So if it's a specific **question** about LINQ, it can be edited into shape.

Answer (score 2):

The new tag wikis make this possible. Questions can be linked to from the wikis themselves, but the most-linked questions will be automatically listed in the tag's FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be convinent if this technology was built right into StackOverflow, I imagine with the release of the new API, it would be really easy to modify a MediaWiki Installation to connect questions to certain articles.

However, it would take a lot of polish to make the entire process seamless and usable.

Comment: It would certainly take a lot of work to make this type of feature seamless, but it seems like something that could certainly draw and strengthen the community more.